# Androi Kotlin flow: How to call multiple task in sequence without many callback

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have 2 flows (flow1, flow2) and want to call 2 flows in sequential (flow1 then flow2) because "flow2" depend on "flow1" result
but want to implement "flow1" based on condition.

```
val flow1 = flow<Int> {
        emit(1) // start loading
        delay(200) // getting data from net.
        emit(200) // get data
        emit(1) // stop loading
    }
    val flow2: (Int)-> Flow<String> = {
        flow<String> {
            emit("$it,1") // start loading
            delay(200) // getting data from net.
            emit("$it,200") // get data
            emit("$it,1") // stop loading
        }
    }
```

-something like that: flow1.checkCondition(somecondition where if it was false, it will not implement "flow1")
.someOperator(flow2) // this is some operator that takes "flow2"
.collect {} // receive "flow2" result

-note: -how to do it with on collect function that receives "flow2" result.
-I know that there are other ways but I want to know what operator is used for that
kind code.
- If there are not some operators that can't do that code, suggest a way that make
code more flat without many inner callbacks.

Comment: It's not clear how your flow2 is dependent on flow1.

Comment: 'flow2 ' takes parameter and its the returned value from flow1.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're describing, but it sounds like either you can use `map` or you can use `flatMapLatest` on your first flow to produce your second flow, depending on the behavior you want.

Comment: but when i collect the paramter is flow<String> which is flow2.
i dont want to make many callback

flow1()
            .map {
                flow2(it)
            }
            .collect {
                println("flowMain: $it") 
                it.collect { 
                    // flow2 result
                }
            }

Comment: Your description is not clear enough to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: -I have 2 function (fun1, fun2), 'fun2' is dependant on 'fun1' ('fun2' takes the result of 'fun1' as parameter).
-'fun1'return flow<Int>, 'fun2'return flow<String>
-So how to call "fun1" then call 'fun2' using kotlin flow.
-note: i don't want make many inner callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [`flatMapLatest`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) may be what you need. It returns a flow that switches to a new flow produced by `transform` function every time the original flow (`flow1`) emits a value. When the original flow emits a new value, the previous flow produced by transform block is cancelled:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    flow1.flatMapLatest { flow2(it) }.collect { flow2Result: String ->
        // use flow2Result
    }
}
```

where [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) is a scope available in `ViewModel`, it can be any other instance of `CoroutineScope`.